# c# console writeline after string

Tags: c#, console

So I am wondering, how can I make a console start typing after a string?
For example: The console says Username > and i can type after that instead of under.

Example:

How I have it now:

```
Username >
i type here
```

How I want it:

```
Username > i type here
```

I hope you guys know what I mean, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Output your prompt text before `Console.Readline()`:

```
Console.Write("Username > ");
```

And the problem you are having is because you use `Console.WriteLine()` which will append a new line after whatever you tell it to write. So use just `Console.Write()`

From MSDN:

> [Console.WriteLine()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.writeline(v=vs.110).aspx) - Writes the specified data, followed by the current line terminator, to the standard output stream.
>
> [Console.Write()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.write(v=vs.110).aspx) - Writes the text representation of the specified value or values to the standard output stream.

Comment: @MatthewDotcom Make sure you accept an answer that you think best answered your question. This rewards people for helping you and encourages people to answer your questions in the future

Answer (score 3):

Use `Console.Write()` rather than `Console.WriteLine()`